# Image not displaying in a UIImageView

Tags: ios

I've added a UIImageVIew to my view and if I specify the image to use within IB then it gets displayed correctly, but if I instead try to add the image programatically then it doesn't display.

I cleared out the image to load from IB and added the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"];
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    iv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    self.slideshowView = iv;
}
```

self.slideshowView is an outlet connected to the image view.

I can confirm that image and iv are both non null when it executes.

Comment: Have you tried setting a frame? Also, if you already have an outlet to an image view, why not just set the image, autoresizing mask and content mode of that image view directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new UIImageView, set the outlet's image property. The problem here is that your new UIImageView does not have a frame within your super view and you're repointing the outlet to the new imageview you created.

```
self.slideshowView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"];
```

Comment: And if you want to, you can still set autoresizingMask and contentMode on self.slideshowView